# Function "self-insert" in LyX is hidden

Tags: lyx

My LyX program (2.3.6 on Linux) doesn't seem to except the “self-insert” function when implementing new key-bindings (while other functions such as math-insert work without problems). For instance, I try

```
self-insert Hallo
```

my program prints the error message:

```
This Lyx function is hidden and cannot be bound.
```

Why is this function hidden, and how can I reactivate it?

**EDIT**: I found a workaround by adding "command-sequence" such as:

```
command-sequence self-insert Hallo
```

The fully working key-binding in the file "user.bind" is

```
\bind "M-1" "command-sequence self-insert Hallo"
```

Comment: does it work if you run the commands from the command buffer? I just checked and it works here for me from the command buffer.

Comment: Yes, it works from the command buffer. Anyway, I found a workaround by adding "command-sequence" before "self-insert". I've accordingly edited the question.